# Search for the longest repeating sequence of bytes

Tags: java

working with bytes i need to find the longest repeating sequence. The longest repeating sequence is 23

> **23**56**23**8888

Since it occurs in a byte list twice in sequence from the sequence 8. 
I decided to act on this path.

1. Take the first digit and check whether it is anywhere else in the
   list if not then take the next number

> **2**356**2**38888

2. After that I check whether the numbers of the standing match for the
   first ones coincide, if yes I put them in a list, then I continue checking (for example, if after both 23 numbers would have coincided), if I do not
   then I take another number.

> **23**56**23**8888

My method

```
List<Byte> topList = new ArrayList<>(); // byte list
List<Byte> result = new ArrayList<>(); // result list
for (int i = 0; i < topList.size(); i += count) {
            count = 1;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < topList.size(); j += count) {
                if (topList.get(i).equals(topList.get(j))&& !result.contains(topList.get(j))) {
                    result.add(topList.get(i));
                    result.add(topList.get(j));
                    for (int k = j + 1; k < topList.size(); k++) {
                        if (topList.get(k).equals(topList.get(i + count)) ) {
                            result.add(topList.get(k));
                            System.out.println(result);
                            count++; // step to pass already checked numbers
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

But my code does not work correctly.

> 2238888

I get the sequence data.Tell me how you can improve it, you can not use string

Comment: 88 repeats as often as 23. Just saying.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What'd be the output for **2323**56**2323**8888? It can be **23** repeating four times, **2323** repeating two times, **88** repeating two times, _AND_ **8** repeating four times...(the last one is the sequence of length 1)

Comment: @zlakad I read "longest repeating sequence of bytes" to mean that of all sequences that repeats at least once, return (one of) the longest sequences, where "longest" refers to the length of the sequence, not the number of repeats, so answer would the **2323**.

Comment: See [Longest repeated substring problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_repeated_substring_problem)

Comment: @Andreas Well, your logic cleared some of my doubts. TY.

Comment: 888 occurs twice, though

Comment: 2356238888 In this case, 8888 is simply the longest sequence since it occurs once, unlike 23 which in this example occurs twice, which makes this sequence the longest repetitive

Comment: @Mefisto_Fell, did you read the comments above? **888** is repeating **twice**, AND is longer than **23**. Please, elaborate a little bit more.
See this: 235623**888**8 and 2356238**888**

Comment: 8 repeat twice in your example, but I need to consider this sequence as one, and not divide it as you showed)

Comment: What should the be the output for **888**? Maybe **8**? And for **8888** would it be **88**? Or are repeated characters to be treated as indivisible?

Comment: 8888 is considered to be an indivisible sequence and it must fall completely into the result list as well as 23 and 23

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any alternative to an `O(n^2)` solution, where, starting at each position in the input, we generate each forward sequence and check if we've seen it before, keeping the longest. Fortunately we don't need to consider sequences shorter than the current longest sequence, and we don't need to consider sequences longer then `n/2`, where `n` is the size of the input, since these can't repeat. Also, we don't consider sequences that break repeating characters, since these are to be treated as indivisible.

Here's a simple implementation that uses a `Set` to keep track of which sequences have been seen before. In reality you'd want to use a more sophisticated structure that's more compact and exploits the pattern in the elements, but this will suffice for now to validate that we're generating the required output.

```
static List<Byte> longestRepeatingSeq(List<Byte> in)
{
    int n = in.size();
    Set<List<Byte>> seen = new HashSet<>();
    List<Byte> max = Collections.<Byte> emptyList();
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for (int j =i+max.size()+1; j<=n && j<=i +n/2; j++)
        {
            if (j == n || in.get(j) != in.get(j - 1))
            {
                List<Byte> sub = in.subList(i, j);
                if (seen.contains(sub))
                {
                    if (sub.size() > max.size())
                    {
                        max = sub;
                    }
                } 
                else
                {
                    seen.add(sub);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Test:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String[] tests = 
        {
            "123123",
            "235623",
            "2356238888",
            "88388",
            "883883",
            "23235623238888",
        };

    for(String s : tests)
    {
        List<Byte> in = new ArrayList<>();
        for(String ns : s.split("")) in.add(Byte.parseByte(ns));
        System.out.println(s + " " + longestRepeatingSeq(in));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
123123 [1, 2, 3]
235623 [2, 3]
2356238888 [2, 3]
88388 [8, 8]
883883 [8, 8, 3]
23235623238888 [2, 3, 2, 3]
```